# Android BLE long lasting connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to sustain a long term connection with android BLE but whenever my service resets by the OS my connection resets (I re-connect it on service restart (Its STIKY))

Is there any thing I can do about it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can do about such disconnects. In fact you should expect pretty frequent disconnects on some phones regardless of whether your Service stays running or not, so your reconnect logic has to be very solid and abstracted in order to simulate long-term uninterrupted connection. I spent at least a month on this when I wrote the reconnect logic for [SweetBlue](https://github.com/iDevicesInc/SweetBlue).

Comment: You have to expect frequent disconnects on Android.  I collected some data on that here: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/05/21/broken-connection